# IOS present modally animation issue

Tags: ios7, ios8

I am using the present model segue for load the next view controller. It is working fine. Now I am using some conditions. After that it is giving wrong animation.

Method 1

```
- (IBAction)loginClick:(id)sender {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainPageView" sender:self.view];
}
```

according to this method it is giving correct animation. IOS 7 and IOS 8

After that I am using simple condition

Method 2

```
- (IBAction)loginClick:(id)sender {


    if (self.txtUsername.text.length != 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainPageView" sender:self.view];
    }

}
```

According to this method IOS 7 is working fine. But IOS 8 it is moving the next view controller. But animation is not working properly. It is showing more rotation and not regular method.

I am totally confused for this. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In myself I found the solution for this problem. I am using the autolayout and some constraint. In my case that is the issue. I delete the constraint. Now it is working. But still I am confuse. Anyhow it is working